# urllib2 download captcha image

Tags: python, captcha, urllib2, mechanize, urllib

I am trying download captcha image from VBB board by using "mechanize" aka urllib2.
This is where captcha locate (login with any username and pass you will be asked captcha):

```
<img id="imagereg" src="image.php?type=hv&amp;hash=c76c6f3c2e0fc3bf32fd99d36555fa04" alt="" width="201" height="61" border="0" />
```

i was try retrieve that image but it is download a .php file

```
br.open('http://www.amaderforum.com/image.php?type=hv&amp;hash=c76c6f3c2e0fc3bf32fd99d36555fa04')
```

I was change ext name to image but it is not captcha image.
Any help?

Below is some info from headers

> GET /image.php?type=hv&hash=c76c6f3c2e0fc3bf32fd99d36555fa04 HTTP/1.1\r\nAccept-Encoding: identity\r\nHost: www.amaderforum.com\r\nCookie: bbsessionhash=25e24573ce64dfc95dbb873667f21787; bblastvisit=1312644421; bblastactivity=0\r\nConnection: close\r\nUser-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows; U; Windows NT 6.1; en-US; rv:1.9.2.17) Gecko/20110420 Firefox/3.6.17\r\n\r\n'
>   reply: 'HTTP/1.1 200 OK\r\n'
>   header: Date: Sat, 06 Aug 2011 15:30:48 GMT
>
> header: Server: Apache
>
> header: X-Powered-By: PHP/5.2.9
>
> header: Content-transfer-encoding: binary
>
> header: Content-disposition: inline; filename=image.jpg
>
> header: Content-Length: 5745
>
> header: Connection: close
>
> header: Content-Type: image/jpeg

Comment: can you open the downloaded .php file ? Is it in ascii or binary? If its a proper jpg image it should start with the magic number - ÿØÿà or something like that.

Comment: Yes it is: ÿØÿà, but the image is not captcha image, it is image with "vBulletin"

Comment: Check the headers your browser is sending when you see the captcha image. Check cookies, my guess is the script is figuring out that you aren't a browser and it is sending you some kind of a default image.

Comment: I got it now :). They have 3 seconds timeout.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a short script that goes to the lost password page, finds the captcha, and downloads the image to out.jpg.

This script requires the [lxml](http://lxml.de/) library.

Hope this helps. Cheers!

```
import urllib2
import lxml.html

headers = {
    'User-Agent':'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; rv:2.0.1) Gecko/2010010' \
    '1 Firefox/4.0.1',
    'Accept':'text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8',
    'Accept-Language':'en-us,en;q=0.5',
    'Accept-Charset':'ISO-8859-1,utf-8;q=0.7,*;q=0.7'}

req = urllib2.Request('http://www.amaderforum.com/login.php?do=lostpw', None,
                      headers)
f = urllib2.urlopen(req)
page = f.read()

tree = lxml.html.fromstring(page)
imgurl = "http://www.amaderforum.com/" + \
      tree.xpath(".//img[@id='imagereg']")[0].get('src')

req = urllib2.Request(imgurl, None, headers)
f = urllib2.urlopen(req)
img = f.read()

open('out.jpg', 'wb').write(img)
```